# use javascript to grab text and align to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website with rows of images and each image should be clickable with a caption on the left hand side. I have used inline javascript (I know this is looked down upon) in the HTML with an onclick event. I have have a js file with some basic javascript. I am using the js file to add the alt tags from the images onto the left side of the photos. I am a beginner and copied to code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/r3dg3cko/pen/ZLryQG) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img). When I click on the image the modal works but the text comes up as "undefined."

I need to figure out how to use javascript to display the alt tag text when the image is clicked. This applies to every image not just one so the javascript has to be for every photo. 
thank you!

[image of modal with undefined text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnEaM.png)

```
<!-- IMG ROW 1 -->
<div>
  <div class="nested">
    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/c1.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/IMG_c2.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/IMG_c3.JPG" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/IMG_c4.JPG" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/IMG_c5.JPG" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/IMG_c6.JPG" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="IMAGES/IMG_c7.JPG" onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```
var img = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

Comment: instead of this `this.alt` write `element.alt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `element.alt` to get alt attribute.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have interest in showing data that does not exactly match the alt text this is another approach you might consider. If the text will always match the alt text the other answer is much closer to your current attempt.

```
  <div>
    <img src="IMAGES/c1.jpg" onclick="showAlt(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity" alt="Smiley face" height="100" data-alt-text="Smiley face">
  </div>


function showAlt(pic) {
  var picText = pic.getAttribute("data-alt-text");
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  captionText.innerHTML = picText;
}
```

See the reference material on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I attach [this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvN2F.jpg) to make sure what you expected. I write some code that you can try.

Hope it helps You.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="myImg" onclick="modalImg('img1','cap1')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="https://mymodernmet.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/elements-of-art-6.jpg" alt="Painting Is Wonderfull" style="width:20%">

    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td width="30%">
                <p id="cap1" style="transform: rotate(90deg);"></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <img id="img1" width="100%">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function modalImg(img, cap) {
      var caption  = document.getElementById("myImg").alt;
      var src      = document.getElementById("myImg").src;

      var imgModal = document.getElementById(img).src = src;
      var capModal = document.getElementById(cap).innerHTML = caption;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```